# javascript / jquery - interchangeable function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am quite new to javascript/jQuery, I wonder when and what function can be used interchangeably? Such as when to use src, or attr("src"), so on and so forth..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use jQuery methods when I already have a jQuery object and the jQuery method implementation does something useful for me that the DOM method does not (such as operate on a whole collection or allow me to chain multiple operations together or provide functionality that the DOM method does not or provide some sort of cross browser support that might be an issue).

I use DOM methods when I have only a single DOM element and the DOM method or property does exactly what I want.  Direct DOM operations that do exactly what you want are usually significantly faster than creating a jQuery object and then calling a similar method on the jQuery object.  jQuery can be very useful and offers lots of useful functionality, but it isn't really helping you (and probably is slowing you down) if you're just doing something that a DOM property or method already offers built-in.

---

In the specific case you asked about, assuming you're talking about an image object, `elem.src` is not exactly the same thing as `$(elem).attr('src')`.

`elem.src` will be a fully qualified URL whether the original `src` attribute was specified as fully qualified or not.

`$(elem).attr('src')` will be exactly what the `src` attribute was specified as.  For example, it might be `image01.jpg`.  It is more directly analogous to `elem.getAttribute('src')`, not to `elem.src`.

---

There is no general guideline for other properties that answers your broad and general question.  One has to understand what the jQuery method does and how that compares to the DOM property or method and know when there is a meaningful difference.  There is no substitute for learning each method/property so you know which one might best serve your purpose.